# Transition from restful authentication to authlogic in not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using restful authentication in rails. Now I just want to change it to Authlogic.

I used

```
  acts_as_authentic do |c|
    c.transition_from_restful_authentication = true
  end
```

and changed the password and salt field to 128 characters.But, if I create a new user crypted password length is 40 characters length(Its not changing to 128 as in authlogic).

Plz suggest me, how to change from restful to Authlogic from the start.

i.e I have restful authentication now.(how to change it to authlogic..plz explain from start)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a detailed [tutorial](http://www.binarylogic.com/2008/11/23/tutorial-easily-migrate-from-restful_authentication-to-authlogic/).